# Displaying a thumbnail with RMagick in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rmagick

I just installed RMagick and am trying to display a thumbnail of any image I throw at it on my webpage.  But the code from the tutorial opens up a new window in order to show my image.  Here's what I have.

```
require 'RMagick'

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  include Magick

  def home
    @cat = ImageList.new("app/assets/images/me.jpg")
  end
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= @cat.display %>
```

I want the image to be displayed on the page instead a new window pops up displaying the image and this is displayed on the page:

`#<Magick::ImageList:0x007f564804bb18>`

**UPDATE**

I need to resize the image before I display it.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [display](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/ilist.html#display):

> Displays the images in the imagelist to any X Window screen. By
>   default displays to the local screen. You can specify a different
>   screen by assigning the name to the server_name attribute in the
>   optional arguments block.

That's not the right method to use in a HTML page. If you already have the image saved, you don't need to load it back into an `ImageList`. You can just display it in your view:

```
<%= image_tag "me.jpg" %>
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry to bother you @Thilo, but I need to resize the image first before I display it on an HTML page.